# Why doesn't Automatic Upload work in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I configured the FTP server configuration, but I can not enable the Automatic Upload

[image]

[image]

Weberver is a simple LAMP Debian Jessie. What's wrong? What I should do?

Comment: Looks like you have not finished configuring your deployment entry properly yet (Mappings tab in particular) -- your screenshot shows that even manual upload/download is unavailable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to goto:

**Tools** `-->` **Deployment** `-->` **Configuration...**

and then the "Mappings" tab. For your selected server it will then have "Local Path" and "Deployment Path" textboxes for you to map your local folders to the remote folders so that the automatic uploading script will know where to put the files.

Comment: Thank you very much. You my hero!